# Can we declare pointer functions in C or this is something else?

Tags: c, function-pointers, declaration, function-declaration

I found this on geeksforgeeks

```
char *getString()
{
char *str = "Nice test for strings";
return str;
}

int main()
{
printf("%s", getString());
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Output: “Nice test for strings”

I tried searching pointer functions but its not this. If you could point me to learn how this is done. It would be nice

Comment: Pointer functions? Are you talking about `char *getString()`? Its a function returning a `char*`.

Comment: "Pointer functions" ? That is not standard terminology. `getString` is a function and it **returns** a pointer.

Comment: If you're asking to return pointers from functions, the pointer needs to be allocated dynamically. Or it needs to be static/global. Local pointers will be lost from the stack pointer when the function returns.

Comment: @Nina *If you're asking to return pointers from functions, the pointer needs to be allocated dynamically. Or it needs to be static/global. Local pointers will be lost from the stack pointer when the function returns.*    Given `char *str = "Nice test for strings";`, where do you think the pointer `str` points to?

Comment: @AndrewHenle It points to "Nice test for strings" but returning it doesn't garuntee the pointer will always point there. When other functions are called or other variables are allocated the stack pointer will shift around and that pointer will be lost..

Comment: @Nina The string constant isn't on the stack. Only `str` is on the stack, and `str`'s *value* is returned. You can safely return the *value* of a variable on the stack. Otherwise `int i = 3; return i;` wouldn't be safe.

Comment: Oh I forgot literals are static.

Comment: @Nina *It points to "Nice test for strings" but returning it doesn't garuntee the pointer will always point there....* Ouch. If I could downvote a comment, I would.  `char *str = "Nice test for strings";` means `ptr` points to a string literal that's implicily `static`. The value contained in `str` is returned - **by value** so the address returned **by  value** will always refer to the string literal.

Comment: It is unclear whether you are asking about functions that return pointers or about pointers to functions. You write “I tried searching pointer functions but its not this.” The pronouns in that sentence are unclear; the “it” of “its” could be the results of the search or “pointer functions” or something else, and the “this” could be the code you showed or “pointer functions” or something else. Rewrite your question to make clear what you are asking about.

Comment: @AndrewHenle "The value contained in str is returned - by value" that is incorrect. A pointer to the value is still returned but because the string is static, then the data is contained. A pointer to the static string is still returned.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-pointer-in-c/

Comment: @Nina "The value contained in str is returned - by value" is correct. The value of `str` is a pointer and it's returned by value

Comment: @Nina: The value contained in `str` is an address. C 2018 6.2.5 20 says “… A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type.” The characters at that address are not contained in `str`. `return str;` returns the value of `str`.

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate of a question about returning a pointer from a function, but I'm not certain that is what the OP is actually asking.  It sounds to me as though he is asking about function pointers...  If so, this is a better option for marking it as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Answer (score 2):

It seems you think that there is declared a pointer to a function

```
char *getString()
```

But this assumption is wrong.

There is declared the function `getString` that returns a pointer of the type `char *` to the string literal `"Nice test for strings"`.

As string literals have static storage durations then the returned pointer will be valid after exiting the function.

A pointer to the function can look like

```
char * ( *getStringPtr )() = getString;
```

then using this pointer you could call the function like

```
printf("%s", getStringPtr());
```